# Describe using polar coordinates the contour line of $f(x,y)=\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Describe using polar coordinates the contour line of $f(x,y)=\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $0$ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$

I did $\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}=k$ the contour line

then $\frac{2(r \cos\theta)(r \sin\theta)}{r^2  \left(cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)\right)}=2 \cos\theta \cdot \sin \theta=k$ is the countourr line in polar coordinates is right?

Comment: why $\cos^2 * \sin^2$ in the denominator, it should be plus..

Comment: @GCab yes, sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Equivalent forms such as $\sin2\theta=k$ may also be useful.